# Delete a SharePoint Online site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, pnp

When deleting sharepoint online sites like below does not work for modern team sites:

```
Tenant.DeleteSiteCollection("https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/segato-slet-01",true);
```

This will tell you you need to delete the 365 group first. Is there anything in CSOM or PnP that can do that for you? So you dont have to test whether its has a group, and afterwards find the group id so you can delete the group first?

Answer (score 0):

Use below PowerShell to delete a site collection from the site collections list to the Recycle Bin:

```
Remove-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/site1 -NoWait
```

References:

[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/remove-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps#:~:text=To%20delete%20a%20site%20collection,using%20the%20Remove%2DSPODeletedSite%20cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/remove-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps#:%7E:text=To%20delete%20a%20site%20collection,using%20the%20Remove%2DSPODeletedSite%20cmdlet).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/delete-site-collection

Comment: Thanks alot. I need to do it from c# is there any similar approach from there?

Answer (score 0):

Use below C# code to delete site collection as well as verify if site collection is deleted or not using **tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading;

namespace DeleteSiteCollection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ClientContext tenantContext = new ClientContext("https://yoursite-admin.sharepoint.com/ Jump "))
            {
                SecureString password = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in "yourpassword".ToCharArray())
                    password.AppendChar(c);
                tenantContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", password);
                var tenant = new Tenant(tenantContext);
                SpoOperation spoOperation = tenant.RemoveSite("https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteA Jump ");
 
                tenantContext.Load(spoOperation);
                tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();
 
                Console.WriteLine("Time: " + DateTime.Now);
                while (!spoOperation.IsComplete)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    tenantContext.Load(spoOperation);
                    tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();
                     
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Time: " + DateTime.Now);
                Console.WriteLine("Verify site does not show up in getSiteProperties");
                try
                {
                    SiteProperties site = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl("https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteA Jump ", false);
                    tenantContext.Load(site);
                    tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("Site is not deleted");
                }
                catch (ServerException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cannot find the active site: " + e.Message);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work for modern team sites deleting the group too?

Comment: I have not tried it for team site with connected Office 365 groups. You can give it a try and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It show the error in my orginal post:(